# Swift single button handle audio record, pause and resume

Tags: swift, button, avfoundation

I am trying to create `audio` `record`, `pause` and `resume` record with help of `AVFoundation` Framework. here, I have done record and stop using single `button` but I want to do single button handle record, pause and resume three functionality. How to do that?

```
@IBAction func record_click(_ sender: Any) {

        // Record, Pause and Resume need to handle here

        if let audioRecorder = self.audioRecorder {
            if (audioRecorder.isRecording) {
                audioRecorder.stop()
                record_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                save_bar_button.isEnabled = true

            } else {

                audioRecorder.record()
                recordTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector:#selector(self.updateAudioMeter(timer:)), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
                record_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                save_bar_button.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will there be a separate “stop” button?

Comment: No separate stop button. Single button I need to handle three operations. when user click the mic button it will start record, if again click it will stop and if again click it will resume. I have separate save button@robmayoff

Comment: From the user's point of view, what is the difference between “record” and “resume”?

Comment: record we can pause and resume to rerecord save file.@robmayoff

Comment: How does the user “rerecord”?

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction func record_click(_ sender: Any) {

    // Record, Pause and Resume need to handle here

    if let audioRecorder = self.audioRecorder {
        if (audioRecorder.isRecording) {
            audioRecorder.pauseRecording()
            record_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            save_bar_button.isEnabled = true

        } else {

            audioRecorder.resumeRecording()
            recordTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector:#selector(self.updateAudioMeter(timer:)), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
            record_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            save_bar_button.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

**Try this**

Comment: Thanks @VictorLucas. I will try and let you know here.